# Issue in genearting the sub report details?

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I had created the report it is getting the values for first name and last name and invoice id but when I add the sub report the other values are not getting it is just printing the headings. Please solve my problem and suggest me.

It is printing as below image.

Main report code:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Usage Rport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="595" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" >
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.GridHeight" value="12"/>
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.GridWidth" value="12"/>
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.SnapToGrid" value="false"/>
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.Grid" value="false"/>
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<import value="org.joda.time.DateTime"/>
<parameter name="invoice_id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<parameter name="entity_id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<parameter name="entityPhoneCountryCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="entityPhoneAreaCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="entityPhoneContry" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="invoiceDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="invoiceDueDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["D:\\Ravi Workspace\\Openbrm\\open-brm-openbrm-2.0\\descriptors\\reports\\usage\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[select co.first_name,co.last_name,b.id as user_id from swiss_cdr_event e join order_process o join base_user b on b.id=e.user_id and e.order_id = o.order_id join contact co on e.user_id=co.user_id where o.invoice_id=$P{invoice_id} and b.entity_id=$P{entity_id} order by e.call_start_date asc;]]>
</queryString>
<field name="first_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="last_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="user_id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<title>
    <band height="20"/>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="111">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="5" y="13" width="200" height="15" />
            <textElement>
                <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{first_name}+" " +$F{last_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="185" y="13" width="140" height="15" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Rechnungs-Nr. ]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="368" y="13" width="100" height="15" />
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Jahr / Monat]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="379" y="28" width="52" height="15" />
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[datiert]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="252" y="13" width="100" height="15" />
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$P{invoice_id}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <subreport>
            <reportElement x="434" y="28" width="119" height="18" />
            <subreportParameter name="invoiceId">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{invoice_id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "run-details.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
        <subreport>
            <reportElement x="435" y="9" width="161" height="15" />
            <subreportParameter name="invoiceId">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{invoice_id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "invoice-period-31.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="185" y="28" width="100" height="15" />
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Gesprächsnachweis]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <subreport>
            <reportElement x="6" y="57" width="590" height="43" />
            <subreportParameter name="invoiceId">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{invoice_id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <subreportParameter name="entityId">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{entity_id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "usage-31-de-details.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="33">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="195" y="15" width="80" height="15" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Seite "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" von "]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField evaluationTime="Report">
            <reportElement x="275" y="15" width="40" height="15" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</pageFooter>
<lastPageFooter>
    <band height="33">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="205" y="18" width="80" height="15" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Seite "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" von "]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField evaluationTime="Report">
            <reportElement x="285" y="18" width="40" height="15" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</lastPageFooter>
<summary>
    <band height="20"/>
</summary>
```

Subreport code:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Usage Rport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="595" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" >
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.GridHeight" value="12"/>
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.GridWidth" value="12"/>
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.SnapToGrid" value="false"/>
<property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.Grid" value="false"/>
<import value="org.joda.time.DateTime"/>
<parameter name="invoice_id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<parameter name="entity_id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<parameter name="entityCity" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="customerCity" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="entityPhoneCountryCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="entityPhoneAreaCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="entityPhoneContry" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="invoiceDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="invoiceDueDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["D:\\Ravi Workspace\\Openbrm\\open-brm-openbrm-2.0\\descriptors\\reports\\usage\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[select e.calling_number,e.duration,e.call_start_date,e.cost,e.destination_number,e.destination_descr,co.first_name,co.last_name,b.id as user_id from swiss_cdr_event e join order_process o join base_user b on b.id=e.user_id and e.order_id = o.order_id join contact co on e.user_id=co.user_id where o.invoice_id=$P{invoice_id} and b.entity_id=$P{entity_id} order by e.call_start_date asc;]]>
</queryString>
<field name="calling_number" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="destination_number" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="duration" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="cost" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="call_start_date" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
<field name="destination_descr" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="first_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="last_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="user_id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<variable name="total" class="java.math.BigDecimal" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{cost}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<title>
    <band height="111"/>
</title>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="33">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="12" y="10" width="62" height="15" />
            <textElement>
                <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Datum/Uhrzeit]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="240" y="10" width="85" height="15" />
            <textElement>
                <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Destination]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="450" y="10" width="42" height="15" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Menge]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="90" y="10" width="62" height="15" />
            <text><![CDATA[Anruf von]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="163" y="10" width="49" height="14" />
            <text><![CDATA[Service]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="334" y="10" width="100" height="15" />
            <text><![CDATA[Rufnummer]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="514" y="10" width="47" height="15" />
            <text><![CDATA[Betrag]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="20">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="360" y="3" width="193" height="16" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="9"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00").format($F{cost})]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="12" y="3" width="96" height="16" />
            <textElement>
                <font size="9"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format($F{call_start_date})]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="242" y="3" width="121" height="16" />
            <textElement>
                <font size="9"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{destination_descr}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="60" y="3" width="96" height="16" />
            <textElement>
                <font size="9"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format($F{call_start_date})]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="450" y="4" width="100" height="16" />
            <textElement>
                <font size="9"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$F{duration}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <subreport>
            <reportElement x="302" y="0" width="129" height="20" />
            <subreportParameter name="invoiceId">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{invoice_id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "entity-details-31.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="98" y="0" width="90" height="15" />
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{entityCity}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
<summary>
    <band height="80">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="242" y="6" width="92" height="15" />
            <text><![CDATA[Total]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="431" y="6" width="100" height="15" />
            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{total} == null ? "0.00" : new DecimalFormat ("#,##0.00").format($V{total})]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</summary>
```

[image]

Comment: `Please solve my problem ` - What do you mean?

Comment: I mean to suggest me how to solve the issue

Comment: and b.entity_id=$P{entity_id}, you have no default expression nor are you passing this parameter so you are filtering on b.entity_id=null, is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: based on entity id only we will get the invoice id

Comment: Another thing is without adding the subreport it is printing the details with the same query.

Comment: Sorry can not understand what you are trying to tell me, in subreport you have in query "and b.entity_id=null", will this work... or maybe you forgot to pass it as a parameter...

Comment: that query is working

Comment: @Petter Friberg please give me reply it is very important for me.

Comment: It seems like your problem is that you don't get any records in subreport, please check your query in subreport...

Comment: Manually tried the query it is working fine.But what is the problem for subreport?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As looking into your jrxml, You also have to pass $P{entity_id} to your sub_report. Currently you are passing only invoice id $P{invoice_id}. As your sub report sql is working on two parameter $P{invoice_id} and $P{entity_id}. if you are not passing it will pick default value or null (if no default value).

One more suggestion, sub report should contain only those band which is required and arrange your text field properly otherwise you will get excel column formating issue when you try to download in excel.

When you click on subreport and select properties then you will image like in first.

[image]

Now click on parameters in subreport tab of properties. Please see the second image.

[image]

there are three subreport in your main jrxml.

1) run-details.jrxml
Subreport parameter map in main jrxml 
invoiceId : $P{invoice_id}

2) invoice-period-31.jrxml

Subreport parameter map in main jrxml 
invoiceId : $P{invoice_id}

3) usage-31-de-details.jrxml

Subreport parameter map in main jrxml 
invoiceId : $P{invoice_id}

I can see in 3 subreport parameter name is invoice_id. So you should change to 
Subreport parameter map in main jrxml 
invoice_id : $P{invoice_id}

And Also 3 sub report is working on entity_id parameter. you also have to pass that value.
Now
Subreport parameter map in main jrxml 
invoice_id : $P{invoice_id}
entity_id  : $P{entity_id}

I am not sure what parameter name is used in another subreport.

Comment: I am using entity_id also in subreport.If you see query

Comment: I am talking to pass entity id from main jrxml to sub report

Comment: We need to entity_id in subreport Parameters as in image

Comment: Can you please provide some more detail? As far I  know when you are running sub report and it is dependent on some value which actually comes from main jrxml then you have to pass it subreport. Let me explain you know , if main jrxml have some parameter then you have to pass it otherwise it gives no data. Same thing is happening with your sub report you are using a parameter but you are not passing it. I hope this helps you. Or provide some more detail on that.

Comment: can you please suggest me how to pass a parameter from main report to subreport.

Comment: Select sub report in main jrxml and open window as shown in image 2. then write parameter name used in sub report jrxml. (make sure it should have the same name). then select the parameter which you want to pass. I can see in image 2 you are using invoiceId but in your sub report invoice_id is written. Use the same name in both places.

Comment: Ok.While I need to print the Invoice_Id in subreport it is showing null and in main rport the invoice_Id is printing.

Comment: for other subreports we have used the InvoiceId in other subreport querys.if I keep invoice_id in subreport parameter it is showing error for other subreports.

Comment: You can use different name for subreport. but that sub report name should match to main jrmxl. Example. 1 : subreport 1 : invoiceid ... use same to that sub report in main jrxml at the time of passing values. subreport 2 : invioce_id ... use this name when you are passing to values to different subreport.

Comment: No it is showing null in subreport it is printing only the static data

Comment: but in subreport there is another subreport we are using for entity-details it is using InvoiceId.If I change it is not taking the jasper in subreport

Comment: I have edited my code in main report with your changes.Please can you check and suggest me.

Comment: Again you did same mistake. In your above sub report , invoice_id and entity_id is written. And you are passing invoiceId and entityId to subreport. Then how invoiceId will map to invoice_id. Please change in main jrxml invoiceId to invoice_id and do not overlap your textfield and subreport.  Or can you please update all your jrxml and its subreports. So that i can look into it.